# How to auto shrink an image when doing fill image?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is what I'm doing,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle, draw=false, line width=0.3mm, inner sep=1.0cm, fill tile image=\@photo] () {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I've tried tile, stretch and overzoom. None of them fit my need. I want the image be auto shrinked to the current rectangle's size. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a complete example? From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, with all needed packages, like `tcolorbox` in this case.

Comment: Seems you can set the width of the image if you use `fill tile image*` (see `tcolorbox`s manual), so if you're setting the size of the node explicitly anyway (albeit indirectly with `inner sep`), I suppose you could set the image width accordingly.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Um, could you elaborate a little bit? I think this is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some clarification in the comments, it seems like what is actually requested is quite simply something like

```
\node [inner sep=0pt] (img) at (1,1) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}};
```

but I will leave the rest of my answer below, in case it might be of interest to others.

---

I'm assuming here that you actually want the image to tile if the aspect ratio of the image differs from the that of the node. If you don't want that, then I don't understand why you're using `fill tile image` in the first place, and you can look at Mark's answer.

If you look in the `tcolorbox` manual, you will find, just below the description of `fill tile image`, that there is a starred version, `fill tile image*`, which lets you pass options to the underlying `\includegrahics` command: `fill tile image*={<options>}{<image filename>}`. Hence, if you have a(n empty) node with an explicit size, then you can just set the width of the image to the width of the node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle, draw=none, line width=0.3mm, minimum size=2.0cm, fill tile image*={width=2cm}{example-image}] () {};

  \node[rectangle, draw=none, line width=0.3mm, minimum size=2.0cm, fill tile image*={width=2cm}{example-image-1x1}] at (3,0) {};

  \node[rectangle, draw=none, line width=0.3mm, minimum size=2.0cm, fill tile image*={height=2cm}{example-image-10x16}] at (6,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if your node isn't empty, and the size can grow because of the content, this becomes more complicated, and my answer isn't that helpful.

Also, this will depend on the aspect ratio of both node and image. For square nodes like in this case, if the image is wider than it is tall, then set the width. If it is taller than it's wide, set the height of the image.

Comment: Also, the `false` key or color doesn't exist by default, so I assumed you actually meant `draw=none`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I asked for. btw, can I just make a node out of an image and leave out all the manual tuning stuff?

Comment: @Amos Considering that you accepted the other answer, I take it you posted that comment in the wrong place?

Comment: ah, I was accepting both answers and I didn't know that there can be only one. I switched back now :)

Comment: @Amos Ah, I see. No, you can vote on as many answers as you like (with the arrows), but only accept one. I don't quite understand your last request though. If you just want an image in a node, then all of this is completely unnecessary, just do e.g. `\node[inner sep=0pt] (img) at (1,1) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}};`, but that's not what you want I guess. Sorry for being slow though, but you try clarifying exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I want :) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Should also work with images other than ducks.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{path image/.style={
  path picture={
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
      {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}
    \pgfgetlastxy\tmpw\tmph
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{center}}
    \pgftext{\includegraphics[width=\tmpw,height=\tmph]{#1}}%
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, path image=duck.jpg] at (0, 0) {A};
\node [draw, path image=duck.jpg] at (0,-1) {AB};
\node [draw, path image=duck.jpg] at (0,-2) {ABCDEF};
\node [draw, align=center, path image=duck.jpg] at (0,-3) {ABC\\DEF\\GHI};
\node [draw, align=center, path image=duck.jpg,
  minimum width=1cm, minimum height=2cm] at (0,-5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: People should only use images of ducks. `:)`